# Copy rows from one excel sheet and past it below the last row with data in the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'll try my best to explain. 
I've seen formulas for this but they wont work for me, or will cut and paste or will not paste formulas nor the lenght of the cells.

I have a sheet called "sheet1", I want to copy 41 rows from that sheet, let's assume  I have data on row 1 to 41 and I want to copy that and paste it in the same sheet but for exemple in row 50 to 91. (each cell have different values, I just want to copy them all into another place but keep everything)

I dont have a code because none worked for me the way i'd like.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the vba code you have tried that you thought would work and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        Set r1 = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(41, Columns.Count))
        Set r2 = .Range("A50")
    End With

    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

Note the *"dots"* in the `Set` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I have this. it works if I use it on row 1 and 2 but gives me a error 9, subscript out of range if I try to use it where it should, on row 1023 to 1105 on my sheet

```
Public Sub cpyRow()
Sheets("Fevereiro1").Rows("1023:1064").Copy (Sheets("Fevereiro1").Rows("1065:1105"))
```

End Sub
Edit: Never mind, I'm stupid. i forgot to delete the "1" on the sheet names..

Is it possible to put this code on a button by any chance?

Comment: In your Post, you stated that the sheet name was *sheet1*.  Why are you using *Fevereiro1* in your code ???

Comment: It was an exemple, like i stated in the first post.  The code I posted had the righ t names and rows where it should work.